# How best to handle a many-to-many concurrency conflict?

Tags: mysql, jakarta-ee, concurrency, concurrentmodification

We have an application feature similar to gmail's labels - you can 'tag' the items. Now this is a concurrent application i.e., this so called 'whiteboard' is editable by multiple users - which means that many users can choose to re/group the items. Basically tag multiple items at the same time.

There will definitely be conflicts but the question is how best to handle it? The only strategy that comes to mind is similar to the famous ALOHA protocol i.e., check before commit if any thing has changed - if so, abort and inform user; else commit. This is quite inefficient IMO.

Here are two similar ideas - one difficult and the other easier by comparison:

Easier one first :) - overwrite changes i.e., the duplicates would just be updated but new ones would be tagged too.

Difficult one: Check for which are to be 'removed' i.e., there could be some that doesn't belong to the categorization (by user 2 say. i.e., user 1 made a change and user 2 also made it at the same time. Basically finding the set of tagged items {user1 - user2}). This is going to be extremely hard and really not worth the effort IMHO.

I was wondering what's the best practice solution to use in such a case which doesn't hinder the user experience and doesn't confuse them either.

(This is a J2EE/Restlet app with a MySQL backend and a Jquery/ajax front end)

Answer (score 2):

The answer to this question really depends on who your users are and what they expect.  If it were me, I think I would anticipate being informed of a user creating changes before mine are done (stackoverflow does this), and allow me to commit changes anyway or roll back.  All of the solutions you've presented seem acceptable .. it depends purely on what you want to do.  If you're asking for how to do this with `code`, you are going to have to post some code first so we can see what you are dealing with.

Another possible solution would be similar to #2 (just overwrite changes as they occur), but keep a revision of each change to allow for easy reversions, and to make it easy to tell if changes were made on top of others.